# If $A+B+C=180^\circ, \cot A=2$ and $\cot B= \frac34$, what is $\sin C$?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A+B+C=180^\circ, \cot A=2$ and $\cot B= \frac34$, what is $\sin C$?

$$\cot A = 2\\
\frac{\cos A }{ \sin A }= 2\\
\cot B = \frac34\\
\frac{\cos B }{ \sin B} = \frac34$$

What should I do with $A+B+C=180^\circ$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan C = -\tan (A+B)= \dfrac{\tan A+\tan B}{\tan A\tan B- 1}=...=-\dfrac{11}{2}\implies \cot C = -\dfrac{2}{11}\implies \cot^2C= \dfrac{4}{121}\implies \csc^2C= 1+\cot^2C= \dfrac{125}{121}\implies \sin^2C = \dfrac{121}{125}\implies \sin C = \dfrac{11}{5\sqrt{5}}$ .

Comment: The last step should be $\Rightarrow \sin C = \pm \frac{11}{5\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: They're probably angles in a triangle, so I think the positive root should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$ \sin C = \sin \big(180^\circ -(A+B)\big) = \sin (A+B) $$

Then, using angle-sum formulas to obtain

$$ \cot (A+B) = \frac{\cot A \cot B - 1}{\cot A + \cot B} = \frac{2}{11} $$

And

$$ \csc^2 (A+B) = \cot^2 (A + B) + 1 = \frac{125}{121} $$

You know what to do next.